# Zoom In Harism Page Curl Library Android

Tags: android

I am trying to add zoom gestures on the harism page curl libray images

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

I have Override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and create an instance of `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener` to detect zoom event. This part has been successfully implemented as shown in `(1) simpleOnScaleGestureListener` class in my sample code. Now i need to draw my bitmap according to zoom ratio but i am not able to implement it as log shows `(2) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()`. Can somebody help me with this error.

**1.**

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            lp = this;

            util = new Utils();

            Prefs = new PreferencesHelper("flag",lp);
            PrefsPortrait = new PreferencesHelper("pflag",lp);

            //llFooterPageOne  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llFooterPageOne);

            scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());

            if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
                index = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            }

            mCurlView = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curl);
            mCurlView.setPageProvider(new PageProvider());
            mCurlView.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
            mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(index);
            //  mCurlView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);


            imHome = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imHome);
            imHome.setClickable(true);
            imHome.setOnClickListener(lp);

            btOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btOne);
            btTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btTwo);
            btThree=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btThree);
            btFour=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btFour);


            llPageOne = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llPageOne);

            btOne.setOnClickListener(this);
            btTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
            btThree.setOnClickListener(this);
            btFour.setOnClickListener(this);

            // This is something somewhat experimental. Before uncommenting next
            // line, please see method comments in CurlView.
            // mCurlView.setEnableTouchPressure(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mCurlView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mCurlView.onResume();

            System.out.println("index : "+ index);
        }

        @Override
        public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
            return mCurlView.getCurrentIndex();
        }

        /**
         * Bitmap provider.
         */
        private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

            // Bitmap resources.
            private int[] mBitmapIds = {

                R.drawable.image_one, R.drawable.image_two, R.drawable.image_three
            };


            @Override
            public int getPageCount() {
                //return 5;

                pagesCount = 0;

                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                int hheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

                if(wwidth > hheight){
                    if((mBitmapIds.length % 2) > 0)
                        pagesCount = (mBitmapIds.length / 2) + 1;
                    else
                        pagesCount = mBitmapIds.length / 2;
                }else{
                    pagesCount = mBitmapIds.length;
                }

                System.out.println("page count "+pagesCount);

                return pagesCount;
            }

            private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {


                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                bitmap.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

                canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);

                System.out.println("canvas width: "+canvas.getWidth());

                int margin = 3;//7
                int border = 3;//2

                Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

                int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
                int imageHeight = imageWidth * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()
                        / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

                if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
                    imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
                    imageWidth = imageHeight * drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()
                            / drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                }

                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(imageHeight));

                if (lp.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    // portrait mode

                    r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
                    r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;

                } else if (lp.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    // landscape

                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                    int hheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

                    int mask = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
                    int size = lp.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
                    if ((size & mask) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                        // Screen is classified x-large

                        r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth)) - border-126;
                        r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border+126;

                    }else{

                        if(wwidth > hheight){

                            r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth)) - border-126;
                            r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border+126;

                        }else {

                            r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth)) - border;
                            r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;


                        }

                    } 

                }

                System.out.println("getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation");

                r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
                r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

                Paint p = new Paint();
                p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                canvas.drawRect(r, p);
                r.left += border;
                r.right -= border;
                r.top += border;
                r.bottom -= border;

                drawable.setBounds(r);
                drawable.draw(canvas);

                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {

                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                int hheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

                if(wwidth > hheight){

                    if (index >0){

                        front = loadBitmap(width, height, (index*2));
                        back = loadBitmap(width, height, (index*2)+1);

                    } else {

                        front = loadBitmap(width, height, (index));
                        back = loadBitmap(width, height, (index));
                    }

                    matrix = new Matrix(); 
                    matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); 
                    mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(back, 0, 0,  back.getWidth() , back.getHeight(), matrix, false);

                    page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                    page.setTexture(mirroredBitmap, CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);

                    Prefs.SavePreferences("flag", "1");
                    PrefsPortrait.SavePreferences("pflag", "");

                } else {
                    //-----
                    System.out.println("current case portrait orientation... "+flag);

                    if (Prefs.GetPreferences("flag").equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                        if (index>1){
                            index = index*2;
                        }

                        Prefs.SavePreferences("flag", "");
                    }


                    PrefsPortrait.SavePreferences("pflag", "1");

                    front = loadBitmap(width, height, index);
                    back = loadBitmap(width, height, index);

                    System.out.println("index case"+index);

                    page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                    page.setTexture(back, CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);



                }

            }

        }


        /**
         * CurlView size changed observer.
         */

        private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
            @Override
            public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
                if (w > h) {

                    mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
                    mCurlView.setMargins(.000f, .000f, .000f, .000f);

                } else {

                    mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
                    mCurlView.setMargins(.005f, .005f, .00f, .00f);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(v.getId()){


            case R.id.imHome:

                mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(0);
                System.out.println("home pressed");
                mCurlView.onResume();

                break;

            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.drop_list, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle item selection
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_option_one:

                lp.startActivity(new Intent(lp,ContactForm.class));

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
        }

        public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //  scaleGesture.setText(String.valueOf(detector.getScaleFactor()));

                counter =counter +1;

                int bitwidth = back.getWidth()+counter;
                int bitheight = back.getHeight()+counter;

                if (counter==200){
                    counter = 0;

                    bitwidth = bitwidth -200;
                    bitheight = bitheight - 200;

                }

                System.out.println("Test Plan "+counter);

                mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(back, 0, 0, bitwidth , bitheight, matrix, true);
                mCurlView.onResume();


                //mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(back, 0, 0,  back.getWidth()+counter , back.getHeight()+counter , matrix, false);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //  scaleGesture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("Mad Plan");

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //  scaleGesture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                System.out.println("Mad Plan");

            }

        }
```

**2.**

```
  12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:533)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at projectname.LPMagHome$simpleOnScaleGestureListener.onScale(LPMagHome.java:620)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ScaleGestureDetector.java:300)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at projectname.LPMagHome.onTouchEvent(LPMagHome.java:592)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2494)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4452)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4503)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    12-09 14:26:02.770: E/AndroidRuntime(7470):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATES I FOUND THIS ON TOUCH CLASS, HOW CAN I APPLY IT TO MY ACTIVITY. HELP PLEASE**

```
public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "Touch";

private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 5.0f;

// These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
   //view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
  // view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
   view.setOnTouchListener(this);   
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
   view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
   float scale;

   // Dump touch event to log
   dumpEvent(event);

   // Handle touch events here...
   switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
      savedMatrix.set(matrix);
      start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
      Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
      mode = DRAG;
      Log.i("saran","mode === drag");
      break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
       Log.i("saran","action up");
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
      mode = NONE;
      Log.i("saran", "mode=NONE" );
      break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down
      oldDist = spacing(event);
      Log.i("saran", "oldDist=" + oldDist);
      if (oldDist > 5f) {
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         midPoint(mid, event);
         mode = ZOOM;
         Log.i("saran", "mode=ZOOM" );
      }
      break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
      if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger
         matrix.set(savedMatrix);
         if (view.getLeft() >= -392){
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         Log.i("saran", "action move.....");
      }
      else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming
         float newDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
         if (newDist > 5f) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            scale = newDist / oldDist; //**//thinking i need to play around with this value to limit it**
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
         }
         Log.i("saran", "zoom.......");
      }
      break;
   }

   // Perform the transformation
   view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

   return true; // indicate event was handled
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
   float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
   float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
   return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
   float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
   float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
   point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,
      "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   int action = event.getAction();
   int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
   sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);
   if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
         || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
      sb.append("(pid " ).append(
      action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
      sb.append(")" );
   }
   sb.append("[" );
   for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
      sb.append("#" ).append(i);
      sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));
      sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));
      sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));
      if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
         sb.append(";" );
   }
   sb.append("]" );
   Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Hey I am not able to scroll through the page after zoom in Do you have any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

try this to add any number here to zoom

`int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2) + **30**;`

i added 30 look to the result.

i hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the code below by setting margins to negative values.

```
private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
        if (w > h) {
            mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
            mCurlView.setMargins(-.5f, -.5f, -.5f, -.5f);//Zoom in
            //mCurlView.setMargins(.01f, .01f, .01f, .01f); //zoom Out
        } else {
            mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
            mCurlView.setMargins(.01f, .01f, .01f, .01f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I am not able to scroll through the page after zoom in Do you have any inputs ?